# What type of probability distribution does the given scenario follow? (Answer only one of the four options)

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics, probability-distributions

An ATM PIN of a bank account is four digits long. A person tries various combinations successively( sampling at random without replacement). Let X denote the number of trials required to correctly guess the PIN. Which of the following statements are true? (Assume that the account is never blocked)

1. X is uniformly distributed.
2. X follows geometric distribution.
3. The distribution of X depends on the value of the PIN.
4. X follows binomial distribution.

Comment: Do you have any idea?

Comment: Are you sure you mean "without replacement"?

Comment: Yes, without replacement!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer, oddly, is "uniform".

Example: take the case of $2$ possible numbers.  It is clear, in this case, that you have equal probability of getting the right one on the first or second trial.

In your case, for instance, the probability of success on the first trial is clearly $\frac {1}{10^4}$ while the probability of success on the third trial is $$\frac {10^4-1}{10^4}\,\frac {10^4-2}{10^4-1}\,\frac 1{10^4-2}=\frac {1}{10^4}$$

For general $n$:  Suppose, to generalize, that you had $n$ boxes exactly one of which contained a prize.  You search the boxes randomly, without replacement, and ask for the distribution of the number of trials you need. The probability of success on the $k^{th}$ trial is $$p_k=\frac {n-1}{n}\,\frac {n-2}{n-1}\,\dots\,\frac {n-(k-1)}{n-(k-2)}\,\frac {1}{n-(k-1)}=\frac 1n$$

Intuitively:  number your boxes $1$ to $n$.  The winner is in any given box with equal probability. Say it is in box $k$  You do your trials starting at $1$ and working systematically, so it is guaranteed that you find it in exactly $k$ trials.

Comment: What would happen if the sampling is random "with replacement"?

Comment: In that case the answer is Geometric, for precisely the reason given in the other posted answer (by @Surb).

Comment: Alright! Thanks !!